# Mariadb - Every batch of extended insert execution time is increasing gradually

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query-optimization, bulkinsert, mariadb-10.3

I need to insert **six hundred fifty million(650000000)** records into a single table. I have tried **extend insert** and **LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE** methods.

**Extended insert results:**

I have split the data and every extended insert contains 1250000. I'm facing issues like every batch gradually getting increased execution time.

```
Batch 1 completed in 40s
Batch 2 completed in 50s
Batch 3 completed in 60s
Batch 4 completed in 80s
Batch 5 completed in 100s
```

It will take 15-20 hours to complete.

**LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE results**

I have a CSV file size 40G, I split it by 500 files. Then I loaded it in Mysql. Here also I'm facing the same issue, every file load getting increased execution time.

[image]

**Table structure for your reference:**

[image]

If it is expected behavior, is there any other way to import the data fastly?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html

Comment: Will you be doing this daily or is this a One-Off

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for the response. We have to run ocaasionally.

Comment: The expensive part of a bulk load is the maintainance of indexes. If you remove the indexzes and then just add them back at the end you will see a speed increase

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm going to try your suggestions and let you know the updates.

Comment: I removed the index, the extended inserts completed in 2 hours(650M records). At the end I added the index again, it will take 6-8 hours to complete. any suggestions to improve the indexing speed?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Answer (score 0):

Sort the data by the `PRIMARY KEY`.  It is likely to be faster to sort a 40GB file with the sort command than to have MySQL do it.

Set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to about 70% of available RAM.  How much RAM do you have?

Have the `PRIMARY KEY` already established on the table.

Don't have any secondary indexes or `FOREIGN KEYs` or Triggers.  Add them later.  Yes, it takes time.

Confirm that you will really need all those indexes.

The data could be shrunk slightly by picking a smaller than the 10-byte `DECIMAL(20,6)`.