# Fastest way to import a large csv in hdfs via aws rds mysql

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, hdfs, amazon-rds

How can I import a large csv in hdfs via aws rds mysql?

I had tried with MYSQL workbench, but it took more than 3 hours to insert just 1000 rows out of 2.5m. Is there a faster way to import csv to hdfs? Also how much time it should take?

Comment: Upload this CSV onto MySQL server and use LOAD DATA INFILE for importing. If the table contains no rows before (or their amount is low) then remove all indices and foreign keys (except primary key) before importing and recreate them after. Ensure that there is no triggers on the table.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you saying that you have a CSV file currently in HDFS and you would like to load that data into an Amazon RDS MySQL database? Or are you saying that the data is in RDS MySQL and you want to load it into HDFS?

Comment: [Importing data from any source to a MySQL or MariaDB DB instance - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.AnySource.html) recommends using `mysqlimport`. It would be fastest to run this from an Amazon EC2 instance in the same VPC as the RDS database.

Comment: See if these help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68281911/1766831